# How to return an id and use it directly in another stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, output

I want his stored procedure to return the inserted id

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertAddress_DBO]
    @Name VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Address]([Address_Name])
    OUTPUT INSERTED.Address_Id
    VALUES (@Name)
END
```

This one the same

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertDocumentation_DBO]
    @Texte VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Documentation]([Documentation_Text])
    OUTPUT inserted.Documentation_Id
    VALUES (@Texte)
END
```

And this one to use them and return her own -
like using the inserted id to put it into the next stored procedure as a parameter

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertEstablishmentByStrings_DBO]
    @Establishment_Name VARCHAR(50),
    @Address_Name VARCHAR(50),
    @Documentation_Text VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Address_ID INT ,
            @Documentation_ID INT 

    EXEC @Address_ID = [dbo].[InsertAddress_DBO] 
                       @Name = "rue de la banchiesserie 85 Golback"

    EXEC @Documentation_ID = [dbo].[InsertDocumentation_DBO] 
                             @Texte = "né en 55555 restaurant fabuleux"

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Establishment]([Establishment_Name],[Address_Id],[Documentation_Id])
    OUTPUT inserted.Establishment_Id
    VALUES (@Establishment_Name,@Address_ID,@Documentation_ID)
END
```

However, I always get an error, because the stored procedure doesn't return the id when I execute it.

What is wrong in my code?

I would like to get the code I could use again and again in each stored procedure I have to execute. I already tried @@Identity, indent, scoped,... nothing works.

Comment: `OUTPUT/SELECT` <> `RETURN`.  `EXEC @var = procedure_name` assigns the `RETURN` value to the variable, not an `OUTPUT` parameter or a column from `SELECT`. Also, `RETURN` is limited to `int` and should never be used for _data_, only for error/status.

Comment: (Also, the assumption is that even if two establishments share the exact same address name or documentation text, you want to generate a new ID and not reuse the one that exists. Otherwise the stored procedures should be checking for dupes first, and only inserting if there isn't a match.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to return something from stored procedure to the context of SQL query execution you may use a return statement or an output parameter. I would suggest you to use the second option. The first one is generally intended to return status of procedure execution.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertAddress_DBO]
    @Name VARCHAR(50),
    @Address_ID INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Address]([Address_Name])
    VALUES (@Name)
    SET @Address_ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END
```

Than you can use returned value in your outer procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertEstablishmentByStrings_DBO]
    @Establishment_Name VARCHAR(50),
    @Address_Name VARCHAR(50),
    @Documentation_Text VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Address_ID INT ,
        @Documentation_ID INT 

    EXEC [dbo].[InsertAddress_DBO] 
        @Address_ID = @Address_ID OUTPUT,
        @Name = "rue de la banchiesserie 85 Golback"

     ...
END
```

An OUTPUT INSERTED clause you used doesn't returns data to the query execution context but send them to the output stream.

Answer (score 2):

Your stored procedures should look like this, using an `OUTPUT` parameter, not trying to consume a `RETURN` value ([which should never contain *data*](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-or-return-instead-of-output)) using a resultset. Also [don't] [put] [everything] [in] [square] [brackets] [unless] [you] [have] [to], [because] [all] [it] [does] [is] [hamper] [readability], and don't surround string literals with "double quotes" because that means something else in T-SQL.

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.InsertAddress_DBO
    @Name       varchar(50),
    @Address_Id int OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT dbo.Address(Address_Name)
      VALUES (@Name);
      
    SELECT @Address_Id = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END
GO

CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.InsertDocumentation_DBO
    @Texte  varchar(50),
    @Doc_Id int OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT dbo.Documentation(Documentation_Text)
      VALUES (@Texte);
      
    SELECT @Doc_Id = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END
GO
```

Now, your main procedure can do this:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.InsertEstablishmentByStrings_DBO
    @Establishment_Name varchar(50),
    @Address_Name       varchar(50),
    @Documentation_Text varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Address_ID INT ,
            @Documentation_ID INT 

    EXEC dbo.InsertAddress_DBO 
         @Name = @Address_Name,
         @Address_Id = @Address_ID OUTPUT;

    EXEC dbo.InsertDocumentation_DBO 
         @Texte = Documentation_Text,
         @Doc_Id = @Documentation_ID OUTPUT;

    INSERT dbo.Establishment
    (Establishment_Name, Address_Id, Documentation_Id)
    OUTPUT inserted.Establishment_Id, 
           inserted.Address_ID, inserted.Documentation_ID
    VALUES (@Establishment_Name,@Address_ID,@Documentation_ID);
END
GO
```

And you call it like this:

```
EXEC dbo.InsertEstablishmentByStrings_DBO
  @Establishment_Name = 'Gaston''s',
  @Address_Name       = 'rue de la banchiesserie 85 Golback',
  @Documentation_Text = 'né en 55555 restaurant fabuleux';
```

And get results like this:

| Establishment_Id | Address_ID | Documentation_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |

- [Fully working example on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5156e3e3f5de55474116b36878f265c1)